# What's wrong in this , anchor link doesn't work and neither the onclick

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, javascript-controller

```
content +='<td>\<a id="{v.payid}" onclick="{!c.details}"'+filecontentdata[j]+'>
```

Comment: I guess `{v.payid}` should be `{!v.payid}`.

Comment: How you are rendering this `content` variable content?

Comment: Probably adding more details about what you are trying to do. How does this line fit in the code and the error or output you are getting would be helpful.

Comment: One sec... Writing some code.

Comment: yes , i changed to {!v.payid} but  the problem is in onclick , it doesn't seems to work and filecontentdata[j] is not rendered on the table

Comment: This is how content is being used   content +="</tr>";
                        }
                    }
                    content += "</table>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the possibly missing quote at the end, there's an errant backslash that may screw things up, and you can't use Aura Expressions in dynamic content like this. You should use $A.createComponents and create the content properly:

```
$A.createComponents(
    [
        [
            "td", {}
        ],
        [
            "a", {
                id: component.get("v.payId"),
                onclick: component.getReference("c.details"),
                body: filecontentdata[j]
            }
        ]
    ],
    function(components) {
        components[0].set("b.body", components[1]);
        component.set("v.body", components[0]);
    }
);
```

Note that this isn't exactly 100% complete, but it should be enough to get you started. See the [Dynamically Creating Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm) and [getReference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_jsapi_component_getReference.htm) documentation for more details.

Realistically, you'll need to build an array of all the elements you need, then use set("v.body", attr) to append all the children together in the correct order, and finally show the components in an attribute:

```
<aura:attribute name="tableContent" type="Aura.Component[]" default="[]" />
{!v.tableContent}
```

Comment: Appreciate your ans, but I will have to change my code alot to implement the above solution and am short on time , can you suggest a qucik edit , i believe there is some problem with escape char as i want onclick

Comment: @DeepBanerjee Nope. Aura requires a reference to a method via getReference. This is not negotiable.